# Go through each row and make p tag same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some advice with this one:

```
<div class="container p-rows">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p class="ck-edit-col-bodytext">some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p class="ck-edit-col-bodytext">some more more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p class="ck-edit-col-bodytext">some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p class="ck-edit-col-bodytext">some more more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p class="ck-edit-col-bodytext">some text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p class="ck-edit-col-bodytext">some more more text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- some more rows -->
</div>
```

each `p` tag within each row has a different height, depending on how much text is in it. What I want to do is go through each row and detect which p tag has the most `height`. Then make all other `p` tags within the row the same height.

My attempt:

```
var pTagHeight = -1;
jQ('.p-rows .row').each(function() {
  pTagHeight = pTagHeight > jQ('.ck-edit-col-bodytext').height() ? pTagHeight : jQ('.ck-edit-col-bodytext').height();
  jQ('.ck-edit-col-bodytext').height(pTagHeight);
  pTagHeight = -1;
});
```

but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the third example in the entry for `map` in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't want it for each ptag, I want it for each p tag within each row.

Comment: The method still works, you just need to loop through each row first, then implement that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan may I kindly ask for an answer with this applied?

Comment: I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first loop through each row and work out the highest `p` tag within that row, then apply that height to all the relevant `p`.

Try this:

```
jQ('.p-rows .row').each(function() {
    var $p = jQ(this).find('p');
    var heights = $p.map(function(i, e) { return jQ(e).height(); }).get();
    $p.height(Math.max.apply(this, heights));
});
```